# Ignore key press on Android

Tags: android, keyevent

It should be easy to ignore a keypress event when I press a different key from 0, 1 or 2, but this code is not working for me:

```
txtInput.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 ||
                    keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 ||
                    keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 ) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Returning true should be the way to do it... What's wrong?

Comment: Why not just `return !(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 )`? Your whole if-else construct is just a convoluted way of saying "not".

Comment: if you want to restrict some characters you can do it on textchangelistner aftertextchange event

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I wrote it but maybe he wants to add something on the else return so I put it as he did... and this is working for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Skizo. I put some code before return false; and return true;

Comment: @aprados Check my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I figured it out since you make an `onKeyListener` the default return is `false`, so if it's `false` and it shows the numbers, then change it to `true` and it will not ;)

```
etpew.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 ||
                    keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 ||
                    keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 ) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
```

As the [`View.OnKeyListener` Documentation says](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)),

> **Returns**
>   True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Also you can do it adding this in your `EditText`

```
<EditText android:inputType="text" android:digits="3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" />
```

Also you can try this method, but it's better the first one... you can use a `InputFilter` as follows :

```
 etpew.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                           int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {

                    if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z3-9 ]*")) //I've removed the 0,1,2 but if you want to control more stuff just add on this method.
                    {
                        return src;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Have you copied and pasted my answer and didn't work ? :O on ym device is not typing the 0,1 and 2, so weird... can you post your xml?